# Lazy singleton with BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, singleton, backbone.js

I am trying to have a Backbone.Model which is a singleton and I wish to instantiate it lazily. I only need to support modern browsers so please do not worry about the use of ES5 getter.

Is this the simplest way of achieving my goal?

```
var LazySingleton = function(){
    var _LazySingleton = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            foo: 0
        },
        initialize: function(){
            console.log('I am initializing');
        }
    });

    return {
        _instance: null,
        get instance() {
            if (this._instance === null) {
                this._instance = new _LazySingleton();
            }

            return this._instance;
        }
    };
}();

console.log('LazySingleton has been declared, but not initialized');
LazySingleton.instance.set('foo', 3);        
console.log('foo should be 3:', LazySingleton.instance.get('foo'));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the simplest way.

- There seems to be no point in `instance`, if there can be only 1 instance, why have it all ?
- Why have `initialize` at all ?
- Why set `foo` to `0`, I would set it `undefined`
- If I were to keep the `instance` concept, I would write this:

  ```
  _instance: null,
  get instance() {
      if (this._instance === null) {
          this._instance = new _LazySingleton();
      }

      return this._instance;
  }
  ```

  as

  ```
  _instance: null,
  get instance() {
      return this._instance = this._instance || new _LazySingleton();
  }
  ```

I would probably go for something like this ( I might have the syntax wrong )

```
var LazySingleton = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        foo: undefined
    },
    initialize: function(){
    });
```